# Environmental variable coming back as literal braces

Tags: templating, assets, 404, environmentvariables

I have my general config file set up as follows:

```
return array(
  'localhost' => array(
  'devMode' => true,
  'environmentVariables' => array(
    'baseUrl' => 'http://localhost:8888/path/to/site/'
  )
 );
```

Then, I have an asset source set up as follows:

```
File Base Path: assets/img/general/
URL: {baseUrl}assets/img/general/
```

The assets pulled within a template get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/path/to/site/%7BbaseUrl%7Dassets/img/headers/image.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

I've used this format with several other sites before, and haven't had a problem. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `config/general.php` file code has some problem with it.

You're missing a closing `)` for an array, which I suspect is a typo, but the issue to your real problem is probably the fact you're missing the required `'*'` key for multi-environment configs to work properly.

See the first warning note on this page: https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs

Comment: Ah, the `'*'` key is what I was missing... (no typo in my actual code). Thanks @brad!